# "Failed to load gRPC binary module" error when running a Sails.js application inside a Docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, google-cloud-platform, sails.js

I have a local Docker developer environment to build a Sails.js application. This is what my Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM node:8.12
LABEL Name=us.gcr.io/my-project/my-app Version=1.0.0

# Container configuration
RUN npm install -g sails@1.0.2 grunt@1.0.3 nodemon@1.18.4
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY ./server/package.json ./package.json
RUN npm install
VOLUME /usr/src/app
EXPOSE 1337
```

This is what my docker-compose.yml file looks like:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  server:
    image: us.gcr.io/my-project/my-app:latest
    build: .
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: development
      IS_DEV_MACHINE: "yes"
    ports:
      - 1338:1337 # HOST_PORT is 1339 to avoid conflicts with other Sails.js apps running on host
    volumes:
      - ./server:/usr/src/app
    entrypoint: nodemon

  mongodb:
    image: mongo:4
    ports:
      - 27018:27017 # HOST_PORT is 27018 to avoid conflicts with other MongoDB databases running on host
    volumes:
      - ../database:/data/db
```

Normally, everything works fine however, I recently imported and initialised the [@google-cloud/logging](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/logging) NPM package in my application and now, when I run `docker-compose up`, I get the following error:

```
server_1   | error: Bootstrap encountered an error: (see below)
server_1   | error: Failed to lift app: { Error: Failed to load gRPC binary module because it was not installed for the current system
server_1   | Expected directory: node-v57-linux-x64-musl
server_1   | Found: [node-v57-darwin-x64-unknown]
server_1   | This problem can often be fixed by running "npm rebuild" on the current system
server_1   | Original error: Cannot find module '/usr/src/app/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v57-linux-x64-musl/grpc_node.node'
server_1   |     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/grpc/src/grpc_extension.js:53:17)
server_1   |     at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
server_1   |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
server_1   |     at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
server_1   |     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
server_1   |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
server_1   |     at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
server_1   |     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
server_1   |     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:145:12)
server_1   |     at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
server_1   |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
server_1   |     at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
server_1   |     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
server_1   |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
server_1   |     at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
server_1   |     at require (internal/module.js:11:18) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
mongodb_1  | 2018-10-09T09:27:52.521+0000 I NETWORK  [conn4] end connection 172.19.0.2:48730 (0 connections now open)
```

In the error above, "Bootstrap" is the bootstrap.js file in my Sails.js project that initialises @google-cloud/logging. This is how I am initialising the logger in bootstrap.js:

```
// Globally required packages
const { Logging } = require('@google-cloud/logging');
const logging = new Logging({ projectId: 'my-project' });
const logger = logging.log('test');
```

I just can't seem to figure out why this error is occurring. I even tried changing my base Docker image to the official Google App Engine Docker image (gcr.io/google-appengine/nodejs) and that did not help either. i can't find any solutions to this problem anywhere. Appreciate any help.

Comment: According to the error message, you can run "npm rebuild" on the current system to see if that helps. For similar issue of "Error: Failed to load gRPC binary module...", please visit [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49758008/nodejs-error-failed-to-load-grpc-binary-module-because-it-was-not-installed-fo) and [this](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/15431) and try their suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By any chance did you do a `npm install` on your local Mac (`darwin`) environment when it should have been done in the container (`linux`)? The grpc binary is for the wrong OS thus the error. This often happens with a local Mac running a linux Docker container.

`Expected directory: node-v57-linux-x64-musl
Found: [node-v57-darwin-x64-unknown]`

The solution would be to `rm -fr node_modules` and do `npm install` in the container.

Answer (score 1):

Rebuild the app by the following command.

```
npm rebuild --target=8.1.0 --target_platform=linux --target_arch=x64 --target_libc=musl
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the project is having difficulty finding dependencies such as the gRPC binary module (repaired with `npm install grpc`) or perhaps where they are currently located  - [more info here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install)

Comment: `rm -rf node_modules && rm package-lock.json && npm install`   maybe?

Comment: @mikermcneil agreed, but all in the container - see my answer above